# Node JS : Can't access to req.headers.authorization to extract JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Hello  I am trying to extract the JWT token from the Headers of my request, but this request does not contain an "Authorization" key with "Bearer xxxxx". I tried adding query parameters but it doesn't change anything ...

The goal is to create an authentication system with JWT. (I am a beginner)

The request :

```
  const signup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await POST(ENDPOINTS.USER_SIGNUP, userSignup );
  };

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await POST(ENDPOINTS.USER_LOGIN, userLogin);
  };
```

In my controllers file :

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  // ====== Password encryption =========
  const saltRounds = 10;
  const { user_password: password } = req.body;
  const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
  // ====================================
  const user = {
    ...req.body,
    user_password: encryptedPassword,
  };
  const sql = "INSERT INTO users SET ?";
  const query = db.query(sql, user, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
};

exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  //===== Check if user exists in DB ======
  const { user_email, user_password: clearPassword } = req.body;
  let sql = `SELECT user_password, user_id FROM users WHERE user_email=?`;
  db.query(sql, [user_email], async (err, results) => {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(req.body);
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err });
    }

    // ===== Verify password with hash in DB ======
    const { user_password: hashedPassword, user_id } = results[0];
    try {
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(clearPassword, hashedPassword);
      if (match) {
        console.log("match ... user_id : ", user_id);

        // If match, verify JWT token
        res.status(200).json({
          user_id: user_id,
          token: jwt.sign({ userId: user_id }, "TOOOKEN", {
            expiresIn: "24h",
          }),
        });
      } else {
        console.log("not match");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ err: "une erreur" });
    }
  });
};
```

The middleware which will be the first code executed in my "routes" file to verify that the request has the correct token before being executing :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.headers);
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN);
    const userId = decodedToken.user_id;
    if (req.body.user_id && req.body.user_id !== userId) {
      throw "Invalid user ID";
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } catch {
    res.status(401).json({
      error: new Error("Invalid user ID"),
    });
  }
};
```

If i console.log(req.headers) :

```
{
  host: 'localhost:4200',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Mobile Safari/537.36',
  'sec-gpc': '1',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"16a8-wyX3X/tr0d8x80MrYm6LBzAWEXg"'
}
```

If someone know how i can retrieve the token il the "authorization" key, it will be awesome !

Comment: yes, it seems that your request header does not contain an Authorization key. What test client do you use?

Comment: Do you mean a client to send requests? I don't use any, the request is sent directly through my front-end.

Comment: The `Authorization: Bearer xxx` header is not meant for requests made by your browser while you are present, but by an application on your behalf while you are absent. You must have authorized that application before (and can always revoke that authorization). See https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/authorization-code-flow and note that steps 1-8 happen in your presence, but 9-10 in your absence.

Comment: if the front end is yours, then your code is responsable of setting the header in the request

Answer (score 1):

If you wish, You can try **axios** as your HTTP client which can prevent mistakes. You can modify headers easily this way,

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
      'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'
    }
});

// Send a POST request
instance.post<T>('/api', {
  data, { configOptions }
});
```

check here https://github.com/axios/axios